# Retrieving the highest value without using the Math.max() function

Tags: javascript

I am working on this problem and it seems to be getting the best of me.
My code is to execute a function that returns the highest value without using the `Math.max()` function.

```js
var arr = [42,13,34,8, -9, 3];

function max(array, selector) {

  var val = array[0];   

  for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (selector == "Max") {
      if (array[i] > val) {
        val = array[i];
      }
    }

  }
  return val;
}

console.log(max([42,34,8,13,-9]))
```

Comment: You're not passing in the `selector` parameter when you call `max`. Call `max([42,34,8,13,-9], 'Max')`.

Comment: In what way is this code not working as expected?  This is a good opportunity to start using your browser's debugging tools.  With the script debugger you can pause execution on a specific line of code and step through the code line by line as it executes, observing the runtime behavior and changing values of your variables.  When you do this, which specific line of code first produces an unexpected result?

Comment: what is `selector` doing?

Comment: The premise is to this:
Write a function called max, which accepts an array and returns the highest value. 

Do not use the built-in Math.max() function!
The code above was one that I used and altered, but I am not completely understanding why I have to use selector at all @NinaScholz

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function:

```js
function max(array) {
    return array.reduce((prev, curr) => prev > curr ? prev : curr, undefined)
}

console.log(max([42,34,8,13,-9]))
console.log(max([-1, -50,-9]))
console.log(max([]))
```

Comment: @Billy.Brown0618 This is the best answer IMHO. This is a good use case for Array#reduce.

Comment: @NinaScholz right I replaced `null` with `undefined` so the comparison with negative values works. Nice catch.

Answer (score 3):

You could just take a check and assign the actual value.

```js
function max(array) {
    var val = array[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > val) val = array[i];
    }

    return val;
}

console.log(max([42, 34, 8, 13, -9, 101]));
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! I will play with this code more. If I were to only want the max, I could remove the `min` from fns, right?

Comment: @Billy.Brown0618, please see actual code, this is only for getting a maximum value.

Comment: cool. as I am new to JS, regarding array[0], what does the [0] signify? the starting point?

Comment: it takes the element at index zero, the first element of the array. indices are zero based.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have. I reached out to many people and they helped me settle on this. Thanks to everyone!
This leads to my next question:
How is this turned into finding the minimum? Wouldnt I just replace (<) with (>) and use i--? And if not, why not?

```
function max(arr) {
    let maximum = arr[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] > maximum) {
        maximum = arr[i];
      }
    }
    return maximum;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a perfect use case for `Array#reduce`. Here's a recursive answer in case you find it useful:

```js
const max =
  ([x, ...xs], m) =>
    x === undefined
      ? m
      : max(xs, m > x ? m : x);
      

console.log(max([42,34,8,13,-9]));
console.log(max([]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function findLargestNumb() {
  let maxNumb = [0];
  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (arguments[i] > maxNumb) {
      maxNumb = arguments[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(maxNumb);
}
findLargestNumb(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the sort function and then return the first element in the array.

```js
let arr = [42,13,34,8, -9, 3];
arr = arr.sort(sorter);
console.log(arr[0]);
function sorter(num,nextNum){
    if(num>nextNum)
        return -1;
    else if (nextNum > num)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```